# How to change axis label size when exporting in Highcharts / Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I want to change axis label size when exporting image using Highcharts/Highstock. Please see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/fx9Rq/#base).

```
exporting: {    
    chartOptions: {
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#000',
                    fontSize: '14px'
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

It seems it is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is known bug, reported to the developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1759

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Hopefully could be fixed in the next edition.

Answer (score 2):

Put this inside your chart: {}

```
events: {
                    load: function(){

                        if (this.options.chart.forExport) {

                            Highcharts.each(this.series, function (series) {
                                series.yAxis.update({
                                    labels: {
                                        style: {
                                            fontSize: 6
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
}
```